# requests: .json() gives error due to JSON format

Tags: python, json, python-requests

I'm using `requests` to make an API call;

```
import requests
resp = requests.get('<URL>')
```

and I get the following JSON back:

```
var sometexthere = {
  "PO_Item": [
    {
      "Comment": "",
      "Shipped_date": "21-Feb-2019",
      "Supplier_SKU": "456"
    },
    {
      "Comment": "",
      "Shipped_date": "",
      "Supplier_SKU": "eee"
    },
    {
      "Comment": "",
      "Shipped_date": "",
      "Supplier_SKU": "3465"
    }
  ]
};
```

Then I try `content = resp.json()`, but I get an error `json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)`.

I suppose it is due to the fact that response includes `var sometexthere =`? But I can't figure out how to get it sorted out.... ?

Comment: as a whole line, that's not a JSON. Only the stuff between and including the curly braces is

Comment: what's the URL? is it public?

Comment: @MattClark his client code is in python